# Python request.get hangs when triggered from Wampserver

Tags: python-requests

Below function (Search.py) deals with webpage connection and searching some user provided input and returning the results,It is working fine when I execute the python code as it is in a file.
But the same code when integrated with some other python code (Main.py is the actual function and this search.py has been defined as a function in the same) and triggering that main file execution is from a html code using wampserver is not working
By debugging I see that  execution of main function is hanging when this search function is being called.

```
path="C:\\Python34\\geckodriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
baseUrl="https://" + "XX" + ":" + "YY" + "@" + "somesite.xhtml";
driver.get(baseUrl);
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "frm_searchWordsPanel"))
    )
finally:
    element.send_keys("To be searched")
    resp=driver.find_element_by_id("frm_runFTSbutton").click()
    Search_Url=driver.current_url
    Search_res=requests.get(Search_Url , auth=HTTPBasicAuth(userName, passWord))
    Search_soup = BeautifulSoup(Search_res.content,'html.parser')
    for link in Search_soup.find_all('a'):
        if (str(link.get('href')).startswith('https')):
            result=result+link.get('href')+'\r'+'\n'
    driver.close()
    return(result)
```

Comment: Did you try to step into the code in *Search.py*?

Comment: Yes,To be specific it is getting hanged at driver.get(baseUrl);

Comment: Add this to the question, then. Every detail may be important.